# Using Google Maps static tiles with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, tiles, google-maps-api

I am trying to use tiles generated with the Google static API with Leaflet and I am facing issues because the generated tile seems to be displayed `"off-centred"`.

My original question has been posted on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739753/how-to-correctly-use-google-maps-static-tiles-with-leaflet).

I am asking the question here in case this site is more suitable (I will also move the question here if the answer is given in this site).

Comment: Easiest way to do it here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/326132/132839

Answer (score 20):

I know this is too late to answer this question. But I want to share my knowledge in this question. For the static purpose you can freely add the google map tiles inside your leaflet. For the static tiles, you can add following code, 
for street,

```
googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});
```

Hybrid,

```
googleHybrid = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});
```

satellite,

```
googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});
```

Terrain

```
googleTerrain = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});
```

Note that difference in the "lyrs" parameter in the URL:

```
Hybrid: s,h;
Satellite: s;
Streets: m;
Terrain: p;
```

Comment: Do you have any information regarding the maximum usage limits for that link?

Comment: This provides the google map as a tile-layer Not along with their data. So It doesn't have maximum usage limit. You can use how much you need

Comment: Interesting. Thought it was limited.

Answer (score 2):

Use the leaflet-google plugin that orchestrates the gmaps api to get the images and provides a custom layer to leaflet

https://gist.github.com/crofty/2197042

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying to get Google Maps under Leaflet and through proxy (like Nginx proxy server), you can use it like this:

```
    L.tileLayer('https://example.com/mygoogle/vt/lyrs=m&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}', {
                minZoom: 5,
                maxZoom: 19,
                attribution: 'ThanksToGoogleMap' })
    .addTo(map);
```

And to save it to your server or cache it in Nginx (Both server side and client side): I do not know that cache is illigal or not !!

```
proxy_cache_path  /tmp/googlecache levels=1:2 keys_zone=googlecache:10m inactive=3650d  max_size=3g use_temp_path=off;

upstream google {                           
    server  mt0.google.com; 
    server  mt1.google.com; 
    server  mt2.google.com; 
    server  mt3.google.com; 
}

location / mygoogle /
{
proxy_pass http://google/;
#proxy_pass http://mt1.google.com/;       
proxy_set_header  Host     mt1.google.com;


proxy_cache googlecache;
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 3650d;
proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_read_timeout 12;
proxy_connect_timeout 12;

access_log off;
add_header Cache- Control public;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Vary Accept - Encoding;
expires 30d;
}
```

Comment: It is prohibited by ther terms of service https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms?hl=es-419 "3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services. (b) No Caching. Customer will not cache Google Maps Content except as expressly permitted under the Maps Service Specific Terms."